# Вызов метода в Java

Tags: java, методы

Пишу метод init который инициализирует массив из 5 ячеек рандомным числом от 2 до 100 и выводит массив в консоль. Однако метод не вызывается, вот здесь " arr1.init();". В чем причина, ведь класс, к которому он относится работает?

```
    public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

   Array [] arr1 = new Array[5];
   arr1.init();
        }
    }

class Array{
int [] arr;

   public int[] init(int[] arr){
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    arr[i] = (2 + (int) (Math.random()*100));
    System.out.println(arr[i]);

}
       return arr;
   }}
```

Comment: Откуда инфа, что не вызывается? Откуда инфа, что работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ведь класс, к которому он относится работает

Нет. он не относится к тому классу. Переменная, объявленная в другом методе другого класса - относится к тому методу где она была объявлена.

> Однако метод не вызывается, вот здесь " arr1.init();"

Потому что вы неправильно как-то этим пользуетесь. Наверное должно быть так:

```
int[] arr = new int[5]; 
Array arrayClassInstance = new Array();
arrayClassInstance.init(arr);
```

Тогда у вас получается `int [] arr;` объявленная в классе `Array` уже не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

1. Вы обращаетесь к масиву классов `Array`, а не к классу `Array`.
2. Ваш метод `init` принимает в арумент `масив int,` а Вы в аргумент нечего неположили
   Код должен иметь слейдуший вид:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   int[] a={1,2,3};
   Array [] arr1 = new Array[5]; 
    arr1[0]=new Array();
   arr1[0].init(a); 
}
```